How to sticky the header of the table in the flutter?
I want to sticky the header of the table when the user scrolls the page down until this header disappears and stop sticky it after the user scrolls the page down until this table is gone.
I am using the Table widget. I tried sticky_headers: ^0.3.0+2, but it didn't work.
Can we do this without using packages of the table(I must use the Table widget)?
Example code:
Widget page() {
  return Scaffold(
    body: SafeArea(
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            otherWidget1(),
            tableWidget1(),
            otherWidget2(),
            tableWidget2(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}

Widget tableWidget(){
  return Table(
    children: [
      headerWidget, //I want to sticky it!
      bodyWidget,
    ],
  );
}


To achieve sticky headers for your table without using a scroll controller or external packages, you can use a combination of ListView and Table widgets. Here's how you can modify your code to achieve this:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

Widget page() {
  return Scaffold(
    body: SafeArea(
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            otherWidget1(),
            StickyTableWidget(
              header: headerWidget1(),
              body: bodyWidget1(),
            ),
            otherWidget2(),
            StickyTableWidget(
              header: headerWidget2(),
              body: bodyWidget2(),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}

Widget otherWidget1() {
  // Widget for other content before table 1
}

Widget otherWidget2() {
  // Widget for other content before table 2
}

Widget headerWidget1() {
  // Widget for header of table 1
}

Widget bodyWidget1() {
  // Widget for body of table 1
}

Widget headerWidget2() {
  // Widget for header of table 2
}

Widget bodyWidget2() {
  // Widget for body of table 2
}

class StickyTableWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget header;
  final Widget body;

  const StickyTableWidget({
    Key? key,
    required this.header,
    required this.body,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        header,
        SingleChildScrollView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          child: ConstrainedBox(
            constraints: BoxConstraints(minWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width),
            child: body,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

In this code:

StickyTableWidget is a custom widget that contains the header and body of the table. The header remains sticky while the body scrolls horizontally.
The page function contains two instances of StickyTableWidget for table 1 and table 2 respectively, each with its own header and body widgets.
You need to implement the otherWidget1, otherWidget2, headerWidget1, bodyWidget1, headerWidget2, and bodyWidget2 functions with your own widgets for other content and table components.

This approach should provide the sticky header behavior you're looking for without the need for external packages or scroll controllers.

Your header is not sticky when I scroll down. This table owns the scroll horizontally. I want only one scroll for the down direction of the whole page.
